# Nutch 2.3.1 with Hadoop 2.5.2 configuration

Tags: hadoop, nutch

1. I experienced with Nutch/MongoDB setup. But I cannot find instructions for Nutch 2.3.1 (Hadoop 2.5.2 data structure) configuration on Linux VM. Hadoop has been installed successfully. Please assist me.
2. Can I avoid Hbase installation for Nutch_2.3.1/Hadoop_2.5.2 configuration?

Regards,
Victor